# Does this inequality hold for two finite sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Does this inequality hold?

Parameter conditions: $a>0$, $x_i\in(-\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{a})$, $y_i\geq 0$, integer $N\geq 2$.

The inequality:

$$
\displaystyle \frac{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}y_i}{N^2}}{1-a^2(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i}{N})^2}\leq \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{y_i}{1-a^2 x_i^2}
$$

I have not found any simulation example to disprove this inequality. I have only found out under certain conditions, the inequality holds. I am wondering whether this inequality exists for general conditions as listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality asserts that:
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i\right)^2 \leq N\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2 
$$
Therefore:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}y_i}{N^2}}{1-a^2\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i}{N}\right)^2} \leq \frac{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}y_i}{N^2}}{1-a^2\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2}{N}} = \frac{1}{N} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N y_i}{N - a^2\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2} = \frac{1}{N} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N (1 - a^2x_i^2)}
\end{align*}
Since $x_i \in \left(\frac{1}{a}, \frac{1}{a}\right) \implies 1 - a^2x_i^2 > 0$, [we have](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713538/help-with-summation-inequality-sum-a-i-sum-b-i-ge-sum-a-ib-i/1713545):
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{y_i}{1 - a^2x_i^2}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^N (1 - a^2x_i^2)\right) \geq \sum_{i=1}^N y_i
$$
The result follows.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! You really helped me a lot!